# how can i retrieve a current value of textarea?

Tags: javascript, html, codemirror

Problem : So I have alerted the value of `textarea` by:

```
var source = document.getElementById('source').value;
            alert(source);
```

But the value of `textarea` is alerted as it was at the time of page load. And I want to alert current value of the `textarea`. I have also tried

```
$("form").submit(function(){
```

But that also haven't helped me. So how can I do this?

This is my code.

```
<html>
    <head>
    <title>Perl WEB</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.guru99.com/Perl1/codemirror.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.guru99.com/Perl1/codemirror.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.guru99.com/perl/perl.js"></script>
    <style>
    .CodeMirror {
    border: 1px solid #eee;
    }   
    .CodeMirror-scroll {
    height: auto;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    overflow-x: auto;
    }
</style>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("form").submit(function(){
    alert("Submitted");
  });
});
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    function execute() {
            p5pkg.CORE.print = function(List__) {
                var i;
                for (i = 0; i < List__.length; i++) {
                  document.getElementById('print-result').value += p5str(List__[i])
                }
                return true;
            };
            p5pkg.CORE.warn = function(List__) {
                var i;
                List__.push("\n");
                for (i = 0; i < List__.length; i++) {
                    document.getElementById('log-result').value += p5str(List__[i]);
                }
                return true;
            };
            p5pkg["main"]["v_^O"] = "browser";
            p5pkg["main"]["Hash_INC"]["Perlito5/strict.pm"] = "Perlito5/strict.pm";
            p5pkg["main"]["Hash_INC"]["Perlito5/warnings.pm"] = "Perlito5/warnings.pm";

            var source = document.getElementById('source').value;
            alert(source);
            var pos = 0;
            var ast;
            var match;
            document.getElementById('log-result').value   = "";
        //  document.getElementById('js-result').value    = "";
            document.getElementById('print-result').value = "";
            try {
                // compile
                document.getElementById('log-result').value += "Compiling.\n";
                var start = new Date().getTime();
                var js_source = p5pkg["Perlito5"].compile_p5_to_js([source]);
                var end = new Date().getTime();
                var time = end - start;
                document.getElementById('log-result').value +=  "Compilation time: " + time + "ms\n";
        //      document.getElementById('js-result').value  += js_source + ";\n";

                // run
                start = new Date().getTime();
                eval(js_source);
                end = new Date().getTime();
                time = end - start;
                document.getElementById('log-result').value += "Running time: " + time + "ms\n";

                p5pkg.CORE.print(["\nDone.\n"]);
            }
            catch(err) {
                document.getElementById('log-result').value += "Error:\n";
                document.getElementById('log-result').value += err + "\n";
                document.getElementById('log-result').value += "Compilation aborted.\n";
                  }
        }
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <form>
<textarea id="source" cols="70" rows="10">
say 'h';
</textarea>
    <div class="hint">This code is editable. Click Run to execute.</div>
    <input type="button" value="Run" onclick="execute()"/></br>
Output:</br>
    <textarea id="print-result" disabled="true" rows="10" cols="70"></textarea></br>
Log:</br>
    <textarea  id="log-result" disabled="true" cols="70"></textarea>
    <script>
      var editor = CodeMirror.fromTextArea(document.getElementById("source"), {
        lineNumbers: true,
        indentUnit: 4,
        indentWithTabs: true,
        enterMode: "keep",
        tabMode: "shift"
      });
    </script>
</form>
    </body>
</html>
```

So how can I get the current value of the `textarea`? Please help me guys.

Comment: store the valus of the textarea in a variable then alert it.

Comment: Well, when exactly do you want the value to be shown?

Comment: You have to execute at some point later. For example as response to a user interaction, after the user changed the value. "How" to do this depends on what exactly you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not familiar with CodeMirror, but what you exactly see on the screen, is not your original `#source` anymore. Instead there are several elements created by CodeMirror, and the original `textarea` is hidden.

When I look at the documentation, I found this:

```
var source = editor.doc.getValue();
alert(source);
```

Or, since you've constructed the `editor` object with `fromTextArea()` method, you can update the value of the the `textarea` before reading it:

```
editor.save();
var source = document.getElementById('source').value;           
alert(source);
```

Notice also what Adam has said about submitting the form. And there are invalid `</br>` tags in your HTML, the correct form is `<br />`.

Please visit at [CodeMirror User Manual](http://codemirror.net/doc/manual.html) for the furher information.

Answer (score 1):

As you have jQuery loaded you can do as follows:

```
var content = $('#source').val();
alert(content);
```

Of course, if you do it at page load, the textarea will be empty (or even uncreated). You could extract its content on form submit, as you seem to suggest.

This code will create a button that will alert the content of your textarea when clicked:

```
<button onclick="alert($('#source').val())">Click me</button>
```

Comment: That doesn't really answer the question.

Comment: Who's the joker upvoted this answer? The content of the alert is still the original value, not the one user has entered.

Comment: I didn't understand the question correctly. @Teemu I upvoted your answer to make it rise, feel free to downvote mine.

Comment: @thibauts Well, the question is quite poorly worded... Thanks for the upvote. I'm not going to downvote your answer either, though Felix's comment still stands : ).

Answer (score 0):

Try the following inside the submit()

```
var textAreaVal = $("#print-result").val();
alert(textAreaVal);
```

Answer (score 0):

if yout want the value to alert when the mouse leaves the textarea you could try to add onblur="myFunction()" to the input something like: (actually if you want it on mouse leave, you can add onmouseout="myFunction()")

```
<textarea id="source" cols="70" rows="10" onblur="myFunction()">
    say 'h';
</textarea>


<script type="text/javascript">
    function myFunction() {
        var source = document.getElementById('source').value;
        alert(source);
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your form does not get submitted when the button in it is pressed since this is not a submit button.

This will not submit the form, and will not alert its' contents.

```
<input type="button" value="Run" onclick="execute()"/></br>
```

Add something like this in the form:

```
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
```

Comment: Though you're right with this, clicking the button executes `execute()`, which has the `alert()` showing an unexpected value.