# How can i get value of text area?

Tags: javascript

i have two files
1)index.php
and
2)code.js

now code in index.php is below

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://web.guru99.com/lib/codemirror.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="code.js"></script>
<style type="text/css">
    .CodeMirror {
    border: 1px solid #eee;
    height: auto;
}
.CodeMirror-scroll {
    height: auto;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    overflow-x: auto;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
Integer : whole numbers e.g. -3, 0, 69. The maximum value of an integer is platform-dependent. On a 32 bit machine, its usually around 2 billion. 64 bit machines usually have larger values. The constant PHP_INT_MAX is used to determine the maximum value.
<pre class="codeguru">say 'hi';</pre>
Let us now look at how PHP determines the data type depending on the attributes of the supplied data.
<pre class="codeguru">say 'hello';</pre>
Floating point numbers
<pre class="codeguru">say 'you r amazing';</pre>
Character strings
<pre class="codeguru">say 'i am fine';</pre>
</div>
<form class="hidden code-box" method="GET" name="sample">
<div dir="ltr"><textarea class="php" name="codeguru"></textarea></div>
<input type="submit" value="Run" onclick="execute();"/>
</br></br>
Output:</br></br>
    <textarea id="print-result" disabled="true" cols="77"></textarea></br>
</form></div>
</body>
</html>
```

and code.js file contain code is given below

```
$(document).ready(function() 
{
    $('pre.codeguru').each(function() 
    {
            var pre = this;
            var form = $('form[name=sample]').clone();
            $(form).removeAttr('name');
            $(form).removeClass('hidden');
            $($(form).find('textarea')[0]).val($(pre).text());
            var id = $(pre).attr('id');
            $(form).find('div textarea[name=code]').first().attr('id', id);
        $(pre).replaceWith(form);
        });
        window.editors = [];
        $('textarea[name=codeguru]').each(function() 
        {
            window.editor = CodeMirror.fromTextArea(this, 
            {
                lineNumbers: true,
                matchBrackets: true,
                mode: "application/x-httpd-perl",
                tabMode: "shift"
             });
                editors.push(editor);
        });

});
function execute() {
            p5pkg.CORE.print = function(List__) {
                var i;
                for (i = 0; i < List__.length; i++) {
                  document.getElementById('print-result').value += p5str(List__[i])
                }
                return true;
            };
            p5pkg["main"]["v_^O"] = "browser";
            p5pkg["main"]["Hash_INC"]["Perlito5/strict.pm"] = "Perlito5/strict.pm";
            p5pkg["main"]["Hash_INC"]["Perlito5/warnings.pm"] = "Perlito5/warnings.pm";
            var source = editor.getValue();
            alert(source);
            var pos = 0;
            var ast;
            var match;
            document.getElementById('print-result').value = "";
            try {
                var start = new Date().getTime();
                var js_source = p5pkg["Perlito5"].compile_p5_to_js([source]);
                var end = new Date().getTime();
                var time = end - start;
                // run
                start = new Date().getTime();
                eval(js_source);
                end = new Date().getTime();
                time = end - start;
            }
            catch(err) {
                //document.getElementById('log-result').value += "Error:\n";
                  }
        }
```

everything is run fine in my code. in code.js pre tags are replaced by textarea and the code in textarea should be run because this project is of online perl editor. so now my problem is i have alert the value of text area by this code

```
var source = editor.getValue();
            alert(source);
```

but that gives the blank pop up. so what i have to do for retrieve current value of textarea?

Comment: It's jQuery, right? Did you try `editor.val();` (if editor is your dom object).

Comment: Why are you melting so much js/jq syntax? BTW, why using that: `$($(form).find('textarea')[0])`? Your code is quite unreadable... And please post only code relevant to your issue

Comment: what about this? `var source = editor.html();` ?

Comment: You also can try editor.html(); as value inside textareas are included inside the whole tag, being returned by html() method.

Comment: OP uses CodeMirror, solution for source code highlight, which do heavy things with textarea, generic `value` or `html()` will return formatted html while OP probably wants proper source code.

Comment: I suppose the problem in the way you define editors stack. You assign current instance in foreach to global `window.editor`, when you do `editor.getValue()` you'll get value of last textarea from `$('textarea[name=codeguru]')` stack. Maybe is just empty?

Comment: no that is not empty and first off all i have replaced pre tags with text area and after that i have to retrieve the value of text area

Comment: Hmm... You asked [this same question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17523851/1169519) a while ago. Both solutions I gave you in my answer _worked_ with _your code_ (tested before answering). Why didn't you ask for more info, instead of asking a new question?

Comment: i think by my whole code you guys can understand my whole problem.so i have asked again.

Comment: Looks like it's not more understandable here, the same comments about how to access the value of the `textarea`, ignoring the CodeMirror totally... Did you try the `editor.save()` solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have created more than one editor in this code. These seems to be stored in `editors` array. Now you want to execute `execute()` by clicking a button, but you're not telling JS, *which* editor value you want to alert.

The value of the first editor on the page can be reached like this:

```
var source = editors[0].getValue();
```

`editor.getValue()` is supposed to give you the value of the last editor in the `editors` array.

Since you have a separate button for each editor, you can pass the editor's index in the `editors` array to `execute()` function.

At first, remove the `onclick` attribute from the button input, then:

After `$('pre.codeguru').each();`, attach eventlisteners to buttons:

```
var n = 0;
$('input[type=button]').each(function () {
        $(this).click(function (x) {
            return function () {
                execute(x);
            };
        }(n++))
    }
);
```

And in the `execute()`:

```
function execute(idx) {
        ...
    var source = editors[idx].getValue();
    alert(source);
        ....    
}
```

---

**UPDATE**

Updated the fiddle code to output to a corresponding field.

And here is [**an updated live demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/G89sK/3/).

Comment: yes you are right. i have tried this and get the value of first editor. so have you any idea how can i get the value of current textarea.

Comment: Thanks bro i have get my answer but still one problem is there. the output of the editor is saved in first textarea. have you any idea?

Comment: @user2372214 Looks like you've five `textareas` with the same `id` i.e. `print-result`. You need to create different `id`s for them by adding a number to the end of each `id`. Then you can use something like `document.getElementById('print-result' + idx).value += p5str(List__[i])`.

Comment: @user2372214 I've updated my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/G89sK/3/), please check if everything is OK now. Btw, you have a correct answer to your previous question about this, since it works with the code given in that question...

Comment: you have help me so much. Thanks for that but again i have same problem now i am update my code for replace pre code with form containing only text area and run button is not there.but because of that the when i am run the code of text area output goes to different text area. can you see my code and give me reply please.

Comment: you have help me so much. Thanks for that but again i have same problem now i am update my code for replace pre code with form containing only text area and run button is not there.but because of that the when i am run the code of text area output goes to different text area. can you see my code and give me reply please.so i am giving you my code in this link -> http://jsfiddle.net/G89sK/5/

Comment: @Souleste_ It looks like time has run past the six-year-old fiddle, the link to perl.js seems to be broken.

Comment: haha, yes, just letting you know in case you wanted to update it.